# Incremental autocorrelation coefficient lag 1

Tags: mathematical-statistics, autocorrelation, regression-coefficients, kendall-tau

I am a developer and I am trying to compute the **autocorrelation coefficient** of **lag 1** incrementally. The problem is I have to test the results with some certified results from [NiST Datasets](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/strd/univ/homepage.html). The autocorrelation coefficient used in these datasets is the following (it uses the time series analysis definition of autocorrelation, as explained [here](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/strd/univ/certmethdef/pidigits.html)):
$$r1 = \frac{\sum_2^N(y_{i} - \overline{y})(y_{i-1} - \overline{y})}{\sum_1^N(y_{i} - \overline{y})^2}$$

I have tried to reuse the covariance incremental formula and adapt it but it does not work. I got closest to the exact results and my results differ in the third decimal digit. It's not a problem of loss of significance since I am using BigDecimal and numerically-stable algorithms to compute the mean and variance.

I am using  $$r1 = \frac{\sum_2^N(y_{i} - \overline{y_{1}})(y_{i-1} - \overline{y_{2}})}{\sum_1^N(y_{i} - \overline{y})^2}$$ which is the standard comoment divided by the second central moment. The problem here is I am using different means in computing them and I have to use the same mean in both terms. Nonetheless, I cannot adapt this to my current scheme. Currently, I process data incrementally. I have a class called Correlation, this class updates the estimators while receiving a new pair of values by updating two internal classes (Sample, which contains descriptive statistics of certain set of data).

I am updating the class Correlation with $$(y_{i-1}, y_{i})$$Then, the first value updates the first sample and the second one the second sample. I cannot keep the same mean in both samples. At least, I don't find any way of doing it. Any clue?

What I am looking for is an incremental way of computing the autocorrelation coefficient in one pass while mantaining my current scheme, if possible.

Comment: Which formula are you using now (that didn't work)? Can you explain the algorithm as you currently implement it? Have you tried it (against the above definition) on very *small* samples, such as n=3 or n=4, where differences should be highlighted more clearly?

Comment: I have edited the question in order to answer your questions. @Glen_b

Comment: You might wanna have a look at Welford's technique:
https://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00401706.1962.10490022